# Gitlab Runner cannot run `docker` commands in `docker` executor

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

This has been driving me nuts as I think I'm exactly following the documentation by GitLab for setting up [DIND using socket in GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-socket-binding) so I can run `docker` commands in Gitlab CI job. But it keeps giving the following error -

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.0.0 (3b6f852e)
  on Gitlab-HiddenLayer-Group-Runner GosSpAyH
Preparing the "kubernetes" executor
00:00
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab
Using Kubernetes executor with image docker:19.03.12 ...
Using attach strategy to execute scripts...
Preparing environment
00:07
Waiting for pod gitlab/runner-gosspayh-project-27874308-concurrent-0qkp2h to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab/runner-gosspayh-project-27874308-concurrent-0qkp2h to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
Running on runner-gosspayh-project-27874308-concurrent-0qkp2h via gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-6984874897-l9z5z...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/GosSpAyH/0/hiddenlayer/hl-tech-blog/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out c48b6257 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false
Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Here is my toml configuration in values.yaml for GitLab Runner installation in my private Kubernetes cluster.

```
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      url = "https://gitlab.com/"
      executor = "docker"
      privileged = true
      [runners.docker]
        tls_verify = false
        image = "docker:19.03.12"
        privileged = true
        disable_cache = false
        volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
      [runners.cache]
        Insecure = false
```

and my .gitlab-ci.yml is the following -

```
image: docker:19.03.12

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

before_script:
    - docker info
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_USER | $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | $CI_REGISTRY"
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY

build:
  stage: build
  # Default branch leaves tag empty (= latest tag)
  # All other branches are tagged with the escaped branch name (commit ref slug)
  script:
    - |
      if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" ]]; then
        tag=""
        echo "Running on default branch '$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH': tag = 'latest'"
      else
        tag=":$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
        echo "Running on branch '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH': tag = $tag"
      fi
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}" -f deploy/Dockerfile .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}"
```

*Note: I'm intentionally leaving the docker-dind service from the .gitlab-ci.yaml file because the documentation says it is not needed.*

Additional Information:

- Kubernetes Version: 1.20
- Gitlab Runner Version: 14.0.0

Running `docker` commands in CIs is a pretty common workflow and I'm starting to think if it's this difficult to setup, I may as well go back to old ways with using Jenkins.

Comment: add a "whoami | xargs groups" as first step of your before_script to check if user is in docker group.
else you should add it : "whoami | xargs sudo usermod -aG docker"

Comment: I'm getting - `usermod command not found`.  Looks like the image of the executor doesn't have usermod installed. Also, the user is root, so am not sure if that would have made any difference even if we would have been able to run the usermod command. Very disappointed with GitLab Runner

Answer (score 0):

See if upgrading to [GitLab 14.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/09/22/gitlab-14-3-released/#support-for-kubernetes-120) (September 2021) would help:

> ### Support for Kubernetes 1.20
>
> In GitLab 14.3, we added support to Kubernetes version 1.20.
>
> GitLab users can benefit from having recent cluster versions in many features, such as the [GitLab Kubernetes Agent](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/), [Auto DevOps](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/) and [Cluster Management Project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/management_project.html).
>
> You can find the list of [supported versions and related timelines in our documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#supported-cluster-versions).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#supported-cluster-versions) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/6509).